# how to update a state variable immediately

Tags: reactjs

How should I code so that I can save the API response to the state immediately and access the updated response outside the setState().

```
state={
 response: []
}

this.setState({
  response: res // res is coming from API response
});
console.log(this.state.response); // it should show the API response instead of empty []
```

Answer (score 1):

Use callbacks:

```
...
this.setState({
  response: res // res is coming from API response
}, function() {
  console.log(this.state.response);
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the method calling setState to be async, and let res await answer. Something like

```
yourMethod = async (params) => {
  const res = await //api call
  this.setState({
    response: res
  )}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) is the recommended lifecycle hook to fetch initial state data

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    this.setState({ data }, console.log('state updated', this.state));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      /* render data */
    );
  }
}
```